# Easel js rotation

Tags: html, canvas, game-engine, easeljs

I just started working on Easel js. I am building a game where users can build their own character.  When it comes to animating the avatar for the game, I am faced with the problem of trying to know the exact position of the leg when it rotates, say 20 degrees, as the character moves because I am trying to attach the shoe (that the user created) to that exact position. I can use Easel js to create the animation frames, but I would rather create them my self. So, If I used photoshop to change the rotation of the leg to a degree, can I get that degree in Easel js.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, If I used photoshop to change the rotation of the leg to a degree, can I get that degree in Easel js.

=> No.
a) This would be high-end image recognition technology.
b) If you have a prerendered frame with every degree of roration for every image, you would end up with a LOT of data.

If animating the character through EaselJS Tweening-code is too complex/difficult, there are some animation editors for other frameworks that will generate code, maybe you can use one of those and convert that code, it's probably just translations and rotations, right?
**[Spriter](http://www.brashmonkey.com/spriter.htm)**(http://www.brashmonkey.com/spriter.htm) for example supports quite a few frameworks and is built to be easily integrated with any framework, but there are more tools like this, if you shouldn't like it.

Comment: Do any of the sprite editors support generating animation on the fly? Because I have users creating their own characters and that can affect the animation.

Comment: I can parse the xml file generated by the editor and apply the changes and then use Easel js sprite builder to build the animation frames again, does this sound right?

Comment: You can either do that or just animate the characters "on the fly" through TweenJS, this might give you a little advantage if you want the transitions between animation look smooth and dynamic, however if your character uses a lot of sprites, and performance is considered an issue you may run into problems with many characters/sprites. So in short: **TweenJS**: Dynamic, requires more CPU power vs. **SpriteBuilder**: less dynamic, requires more memory(but probably not an issue)

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you add the shoe to the leg and rotate them together?

```
var leg = new createjs.Container();
//add some graphics
var shoe = new createjs.Container();
//add some graphics

leg.addChild(shoe);
leg.rotation = 15;
```

Comment: yes, it's hard for me to create frames using easel js as the movement can become more complex. I need a way to recognize that a leg has been rotated a certain degree by comparing the initial image with the rotated one.